# fast JSON to data.frame/data.table

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have this `R` code to convert `JSON` data to a `data.frame`. It works fine but it is rather slow for huge JSON files. What's the more efficient way to do this (won't mind having a `data.table` output)?

```
    json_data <- fromJSON(json_dt_url)
    json_data <- json_data[['data']]
    my_df <- data.frame()
    for (i in 1:length(json_data))
    {
      my_df <- rbind(my_df, as.data.frame(json_data[[i]]))
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `rbindlist` from `data.table`? You can use `fill=TRUE` if column names are not identical.

Comment: I'm not convinced you need to loop over each piece of `json_data`. I'm pretty sure the `jsonlite` package for example will deal with the whole structure in one go with a little effort. Can you provide a simple example of some json data that you are using?

Comment: actually having a representative sample of your JSON wld rly be helpful. not sure how one cld expect assistance w/o it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for fast JSON parsing, take a look at [`RcppSimdJson`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppsimdjson).

```r
library(RcppSimdJson)
jsonfile <- system.file("jsonexamples", "small", "demo.json", package="RcppSimdJson")
res <- fload(jsonfile)

str(res)
#> List of 1
#>  $ Image:List of 6
#>   ..$ Width    : int 800
#>   ..$ Height   : int 600
#>   ..$ Title    : chr "View from 15th Floor"
#>   ..$ Thumbnail:List of 3
#>   .. ..$ Url   : chr "http://www.example.com/image/481989943"
#>   .. ..$ Height: int 125
#>   .. ..$ Width : int 100
#>   ..$ Animated : logi FALSE
#>   ..$ IDs      : int [1:4] 116 943 234 38793
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Using the benchmarking code from the package, we can compare different parsing approaches:

```r
file <- system.file("jsonexamples", "mesh.json", package = "RcppSimdJson")

res <- bench::mark(
  RcppSimdJson = RcppSimdJson::fload(file),
  jsonlite = jsonlite::fromJSON(file),
  jsonify = jsonify::from_json(file),
  RJSONIO = RJSONIO::fromJSON(file),
  ndjson = ndjson::stream_in(file),
  check = FALSE
)

res
#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#>   expression        min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 RcppSimdJson   1.51ms   1.67ms    582.      5.82MB     5.98
#> 2 jsonlite      44.68ms  48.95ms     18.8     2.74MB    22.6 
#> 3 jsonify        9.76ms  11.34ms     87.5     1.12MB    43.7 
#> 4 RJSONIO       33.11ms  35.17ms     28.6     2.93MB     3.82
#> 5 ndjson       136.35ms 138.67ms      7.21    9.41MB    30.6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

We see that RcppSimdJson is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
data2 <- fromJSON("data.json", flatten = TRUE)
```

reference https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/f/vignettes/json-apis.Rmd

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
library(jsonlite)
json_data <- read_json("data.json", simplifyVector = TRUE)
```

Include the sample input so that I can test the solution myself!